# Likely, easy promises error with ES6

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm going nuts with this code. I had tried everything I could think off, and I know is promises-related...but I can't get it working!

The original code is not as simple as the one I'm sharing, but this is te core of the problem:

- Lets have two filled arrays, and two empty arrays.
- Then 'crearMazo' must run a loop of one of the filled arrays, searching on my mongodb (mongoose) for those strings, and pushing the resulting _id on one of the empty arrays.

Well, It doesn't work. **The last console.log show an empty array**, even when the console.log inside the loop do print the array.

I know...I'm doing the promises wrong (obviously)...but I can't find where :(

```js
var cartas = ['Lorem', 'Lorem2', 'Lorem3', 'Lorem4', 'Lorem5', 'Lorem6', 'Lorem7', 'Lorem8'];
var cartas2 = ['Lorem', '2Lorem', '3Lorem', '4Lorem', '5Lorem', '6Lorem', '7Lorem', '8Lorem'];
var newMazo = [];
var newMazo2 = [];


let crearMazo = function (c,m) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for(var i in c){
        Card.findOne({'nombre': c[i]}, '_id').then( carta => {
          m.push(carta._id);
        });
      }
      resolve(m);
    }, 0);
  });
};

crearMazo(cartas,newMazo)
  .then(crearMazo(cartas2,newMazo2))
  .then(() => {
     console.log('mazo: '+ newMazo);
     console.log('mazo: '+ newMazo2);
});
```

Comment: I guess the second `console.log()` should print `newMazo2` instead of `newMazo`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass a callback as the argument to `then`, not a promise. You could use

```
crearMazo(cartas,newMazo)
.then(() => crearMazo(cartas2,newMazo2))
.then(() => {
    console.log('mazo: '+ newMazo);
    console.log('mazo: '+ newMazo);
});
```

but the proper solution would be to run them in parallel, and use their respective results:

```
Promise.all([
  crearMazo(cartas, []),
  crearMazo(cartas2, [])
]).then(([newMazo, newMazo2]) => {
    console.log('mazo1: '+ newMazo);
    console.log('mazo2: '+ newMazo2);
});
```

---

Also you are starting asynchronous actions in a loop here, and creating multiple promises for them - without awaiting any of them. You'll want

```
function crearMazo(c, m) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0)) // is that actually needed?
  .then(() => {
    var promises = c.map(n =>
      Card.findOne({'nombre': n}, '_id').then(carta => carta._id);
    );
    return Promise.all(promises);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^
  }).then(res =>
    m.concat(res)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer, @bergi :)  

I'm still having the same problem after applying the proper solution :(  
I think that the problem is that the mongoose query doesn't 'send back' the array (I don't even know how to 'say' it, sorry). If I add a "console.log('mazo query: '+ m);" after the "m.push(carta._id);", I get the correct array on console.log at the end of the loop. But mazo1 and mazo2 are still empty.

Comment: Oh wait, I completely overlooked that you're using promises inside a loop there. You will have to use `Promise.all` on all the promises that you create in there, to wait for them.

Comment: Hey! We're getting somewhere :) : Now I'm getting at the final arrays "mazo1: ,,,,,,,".

Comment: That probably means that the `_id`s of the objects you are receiving are `null`, `undefined`, or the empty string.

Comment: In fact, it isn't :( "console.log(carta._id);" before carta._id prints the correct ids at console.log. But it still print them after mazo1 and mazo2, btw.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/arkdelkaos/d0ff05a7eb7948f339a8 (maybe this'll make it easier :))

Comment: If you are using an arrow function with braces, you must not forget the `return` keyword.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you're right :) When I first tried your code, I got a error on babel, and totally forgot the return :) Thank you very much! (I think this is the first time I have done a question without getting a bad reply or something xD You are the nicest person I have met on Stack Overflow xD Maybe this is the beginning of the end of my bad experiences around here. Its hard to avoid this community being a programmer :) )